# How do I parse youtube xml for a specific entry?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, youtube

I am trying to return the duration of the video but am having trouble.

```
#YOUTUBE FEED
#download the file:
file = urllib2.urlopen('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/2s0vk2wEMtA')
#convert to string:
data = file.read()
#close file because we dont need it anymore:
file.close()

#entire feed
root = etree.fromstring(data)

for entry in root:
    for item in entry:
        print item
```

When I print item, I see as the last element:

```
Element '{http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007}duration' at 0x10c4fb7d0
```

But I don't know how to get the value from this.  Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

media = root.find('{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}group')
length = media.find('{http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007}duration').attrib.get("seconds")
print length

Comment: As a note, using the json return data is much simpler and cleaner. For example, take a look at this url and you'll see how much easier it is to extract the duration. I know big chunks of code look ugly in comments, but you could use: 

`import json
import urllib2


urlfile = urllib2.urlopen('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/2s0vk2wEMtA?v=2&alt=jsonc')
jsonString = urlfile.read()
urlfile.close()
jsonData = json.loads(jsonString)

print jsonData["data"]["duration"]`